# Unable to see the Manager External User option, how to enable it in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I am new to the salesforce and I am not able to see the "Manage External User" in my window why ?

[image]

[image]

**Like Below why ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure that **Communities** is enabled in your org.
2. Ensure that your profile has **Manage External Users** permission.
3. Ensure that Manage External User button is added to contact **Layout**.
4. Ensure that the contact is associated with a **account**.

If the issue happens in a sandbox you must ensure that there are appropriate licenses available. If the sandbox was created before the production org had community license then the "Manage External Button" will not be there in the sandbox. In such case ensure that production org has the required license, then refresh the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It would be worth to mentioned the steps, it will help for someone like me as a beginner to this platform

Comment: Refer to this link for steps : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213565&type=1

Comment: Note: Be sure to check whether the Contact is associated with an Account. If the Contact is not associate to any Account, then the 'Manage External User' button will not be available.